# jQuery Mobile page transition from left to right

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I got an android phonegap jquery application. In which I am changing my page using the "swipeleft" function.

When I swipe left I wanna show the next page and on swipe right I wanna show the prev page.

By this code every thing working fine. But

Everytime newpage coming from Right to Left. Ie logically I wanna show Previous page sliding from Left to Right.

Here is the code which I am using

```
$("html").delegate("body", "swipeleft", function() {
$.mobile.changePage("index.html", {
        transition : "slide"
    });
});
});
```

Any code in jQuerymobile such as slideleft ?

I tried many .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried with `reverse:true`.

```
$("html").delegate("body", "swipeleft", function() {
$.mobile.changePage("index.html", {
        transition : "slide"
        reverse:true
    });
});
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply ... and when I tried this , this will leads to next page and from there it again called and going to one more page back.. ie event firing more times.. any idea ?

Comment: pls check if you have attached the event twice somewhere in some other js file.